# How to add customized icons for bookmarks in ubuntu. google chrome?

Tags: linux, google-chrome

I use google chrome on ubuntu 12.04. It would be very nice if there is a way to change the icon for folders and weblinks in the chrome bookmarks without using an extension. There exists a way on windows. Can somebody tell me a way on linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an icon to bookmarks in chrome:

1. Export the bookmarks in an html file
2. Convert the png/jpg image to base64 string ( [online conversion](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter) )
3. open the exported bookmarks file in a text editor and the following tag to the entry of the link you want to add the icon to

   ICON="data:image/< png OR jpeg OR jpg >;base64,< base64-string >"

Import the bookmarks file back into chrome.